# Access denied when user tries to edit his Content Profile

Tags: 6, users

I’m having a strange problem on one of my Drupal sites running Drupal 6..

I’ve the Content Profile module installed and using Tab Tamer to create some tabs on the “My Profile” page where one of these tabs is “Edit my Profile” which directs to **domain.com/user/uid/profile/profil**

It works fine for me as Admin, it works fine for other users that are just regular registered users, but for one user both the “Edit my profile” tab is gone and when I try to manual enter the URL I get an access denied. I can’t seem to find anything different about the particular user when comparing to other registered users.

I’ve googled the problem and found that there is (or at least has been) some issues about the permission in the Content Profile, but since it works for everyone but this user I’m not sure that whether this is a bug in the permissions with the module or there is some strange other permissions that denies this user access.

I tried to change to users role to administrator, and then he has access to editing his profile – but when changing it back, same issue occurs.

Does anyone have similar experience or a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the node as an administrator
2. On the node edit form, under "Authoring Information" set the author to the content profile user
3. Save content profile node with updated author information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to save that profile by administrator (remember to save owner as this user -> not admin)